# InnerText in Python

Tags: c#, python

Is there an equivalent to the c# [`XmlNode.InnerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext.aspx) Property in Python?

If not, is there a straightforward way to implement it in Python? I thought I found something [here](http://www.chaingang.org/bcc/2011/09/12/inner-text/), but it seems to concatenate the values of the node and child nodes in the wrong order.

Comment: MiniDOM. Perhaps there is a straightforward way using ElementTree?

Comment: I have found a solution to my question [here...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11123399)

Comment: It might be easy to use xmltodict and then extract the value you want.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little recursive function that works with [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
def innertext(tag):
  return (tag.text or '') + ''.join(innertext(e) for e in tag) + (tag.tail or '')
```

Example usage:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('somefile.xml').getroot()
print innertext(root)
```