# Extracting text from XML node with minidom

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

I've looked through several posts but I haven't quite found any answers that have solved my problem.

Sample XML =

```
<TextWithNodes>
<Node id="0"/>TEXT1<Node id="19"/>TEXT2 <Node id="20"/>TEXT3<Node id="212"/>
</TextWithNodes>
```

So I understand that usually if I had extracted `TextWithNodes` as a `NodeList` I would do something like

```
nodeList = TextWithNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('Node')
for a in nodeList:
    node = a.nodeValue
    print node
```

All I get is `None`. I've read that you must write `a.childNodes.nodeValue` but there isn't a child node to the node list since it looks like all the `Node` Ids are closing tags? If I use `a.childNodes` I get `[]`.

When I get the node type for `a` it is type 1 and `TEXT_NODE` = 3. I'm not sure if that is helpful.

I would like to extract `TEXT1`, `TEXT2`, etc.

Comment: Your `TEXT1`, `TEXT2` etc. are not actually party of any element. Should your XML be `<Node id="0">TEXT1</Node><Node id="19">TEXT2</Node><Node id="20">TEXT3</Node><Node id="212" />`? Also, is there a closing `<TextWithNodes>` tag?

Comment: Also, I would strongly recommend using [`xml.etree.ElemetTree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (part of the standard library) for working with XML in Python. It is a far simpler and more pythonic interface. For example, in `xml.dom` you must use `element.childNodes.nodeValue` to get the text associated with `element`, in etree this is simply `element.text`.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks, that was what I thought since it was all closing tags which really confused me.  I'm not sure how valid this xml file is, it was just an output of a text engineering software for annotation that I need to parse into excel.  I will look into ElementTree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `lxml` right from the docs:

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

xml = etree.parse(StringIO('''<TextWithNodes>
<Node id="0"/>TEXT1<Node id="19"/>TEXT2 <Node id="20"/>TEXT3<Node id="212"/></TextWithNodes>'''))

xml.xpath("//text()")
Out[43]: ['\n', 'TEXT1', 'TEXT2 ', 'TEXT3']
```

You also can extract the text of an specific node:

```
xml.find(".//Node[@id='19']").text
```

The issue here is the text in the XML doesn't belong to any node.

Comment: More precisely, the text in the XML belongs to the `TextWithNodes` element but not to the `Node` elements. The text nodes and `Node` elements are siblings, not child-parent.

Comment: Thanks @FrancisAvila I'm still trying to get organized in my head of the xml structure and that was really helpful!

Comment: @Jasmine, might be that. I added `</TextWithNodes>` at the end. If you try my code it will work.

Comment: When I try to extract the text of the specific node, I get "None"?

Comment: Yes, because the nodes you have in the XML are empty: `<Node id="0"/>` is the same as `<Node id="0"></Node>`. You should write something like `<Node id="0">TEXT1</Node>`

Comment: @DiegoNavarro So, the best way would be to reformat this .xml file? (It's not something I wrote, but an output of a text processing software GATE).  My goal here was to extract the Node id value along with the Text associated with that value but it seems quite difficult with this weird xml file

Comment: @Jasmine, `lxml` can try to fix broken XML using a custom [parser](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) but in this case it doesn't work. I'm afraid you'll have to reformat the xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ElementTree api instead of minidom for your task (as explained in the other answers here), but if you need to use minidom, here is a solution.

What you are looking for was added to DOM level 3 as the [`textContent` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent).  Minidom only supports level 1.

However you can emulate textContent pretty closely with this function:

```
def textContent(node):
    if node.nodeType in (node.TEXT_NODE, node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE):
        return node.nodeValue
    else:
        return ''.join(textContent(n) for n in node.childNodes)
```

Which you can then use like so:

```
x = minidom.parseString("""<TextWithNodes>
<Node id="0"/>TEXT1<Node id="19"/>TEXT2 <Node id="20"/>TEXT3<Node id="212"/></TextWithNodes>""")

twn = x.getElementsByTagName('TextWithNodes')[0]

assert textContent(twn) == u'\nTEXT1TEXT2 TEXT3'
```

Notice how I got the text content of the parent node `TextWithNodes`. This is because your `Node` elements are *siblings* of those text nodes, not parents of them.

Comment: Where is the text extracted to?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "extracted to". The text is returned by the `textContent` function.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`xml.etree.ElemetTree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (which is similar to lxml which @DiegoNavrro used in his answer, except that etree in part of the standard library and doesn't have XPATH etc.) you can give the following a go:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

xml_string = """<TextWithNodes>
<Node id="0"/>TEXT1<Node id="19"/>TEXT2 <Node id="20"/>TEXT3<Node id="212"/>
</TextWithNodes>
"""

xml_etree = etree.fromstring(xml_string)

text = [element.tail for element in xml_etree]
# `text` will be ['TEXT1', 'TEXT2 ', 'TEXT3', '\n']
```

Note, this assumes that the XML `<Node id="0"/>TEXT1`... is correct. Because the text follows a closing tag, it becomes the tag's tail text. It is not the elements nodeValue, which is why in your code in the question you are getting `None`s.

If you wanted to parse some XML like `<Node id="0">TEXT1</Node>` you would have to replace the line `[element.tail for element in xml_etree]` with `[element.text for element in xml_etree]`.