# Most efficient method to extract data from this XML file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, elementtree

XML File Sample

```
<GateDocument> 
  <GateDocumentFeatures>
    ...
  </GateDocumentFeatures>
  <TextWithNodes>
    <Node id="0"/>
    MESSAGE SET
    <Node id="19"/> 
    <Node id="20"/>
    1. 1/1/09 - sample text 1
    <Node id="212"/>
    sample text 2
    <Node id="223"/>
    sample text 3
    ...
    <Node id="160652"/>
  </TextWithNodes>
  <AnnotationSet></AnnotationSet>
  <AnnotationSet Name="SomeName">
    ...
  </AnnotationSet>
</GateDocument>
```

Just to start off, this is the first I'm coding in Python and dealing with XML, so sorry if I miss really obvious things!

My goal is to extract the sample text at specific node ids.

First attempt - I used minidom, which did not give me the correct methods in dealing with the extraction (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122736/extracting-text-from-xml-node-with-minidom) due to this weird format of the node ids in self-closing tags.

Second attempt - I took up suggestions in looking at lxml, I have successfully extracted the text to something like this:

```
['\n\t\t','n\t\tMESSAGE SET\n\t\t','\n\t\t','\n\t\t1. 1/1/09 - sample text 1,....,'\n\t']
```

With some clean up, I think I can get the text fine, however, I lose the associated node id value.

with the code:

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO
xmlfile = ('C:\...AnnotationsXML.xml')
xmldoc = etree.parse(xmlfile)  
print xmldoc.xpath("//TextWithNodes/text()")
```

So I guess my questions is:

1. Is there a way to extract the above without the \n\t\t? I read that it is the space formating (ie tab) but I am not sure where the `<Node id = 0>` went.
2. Is there perhaps a better or more efficient method in extraction for this file?

Thanks!

Comment: Either use forward slashes in your path or use a raw string (r'...') on windows, or else you'll find that certain paths suddenly have newlines and tab characters in them.

Comment: What is the connection between `Node` elements and the text interspersed among those elements? This XML format appears to be very terrible.

Comment: @FrancisAvila I believe the text analysis software (GATE) allows for annotation of text.  Thus I can pick out a word/phrase and annotate it with a characteristic.  The node id I believe is the starting index of the entire document, if the entire document was a string. (if I describe it correctly)

Comment: That description is not particularly illuminating. The issue here is that you seem to be expressing some kind of "containment" relationship between a node and a string of text, but the XML very much does not express any such relationship. So either this XML format is very poorly designed, or you misunderstand the underlying data model that the XML is expressing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```py
In [1]: from lxml import etree

In [2]: tree = etree.parse('awful.xml')

In [3]: data = {int(node.attrib['id']): node.tail.strip()
   ...: for node in tree.xpath('//TextWithNodes/Node') if node.tail.strip()}

In [4]: data
Out[4]: 
{0: 'MESSAGE SET',
 20: '1. 1/1/09 - sample text 1',
 212: 'sample text 2',
 223: 'sample text 3'}
```

[`strip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is used to get rid of stuff like `\t\n` and [`tail`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-element-class) takes the text after the tag.

Comment: +1 for elegant use of dictionary comprehension. The duplicated call to `node.tail.strip()` is unfortunate, but unless/until Python supports *en passant* assignment (*ha! as if!*), unavoidable.

Comment: Wonderful.  Staring at it and going to pick it apart piece by piece until I master every element of this solution in detail.  Quick question - my message comes out but is not in order of the node id (however, it is all present), I was just curious as to `In[3]` does it not parse that in order from start index 0? `{0:'TEXT',40960:'TEXT2',106499:'TEXT3',90113:'TEXT4'}`

Comment: @Jasmine I think it is parsed in order, the thing is that the data is then saved to a dictionary (you can change that, of course), and dictionaries don't have order. You said you needed to associate text to ids, so I used a dict. You can choose a more suitable option for you, but dict is quite a flexible structure. If you need to store it ordered (for sure), use a list instead.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Ah I see, coming from only java experience I never know what structure these variables are.  I can work with dic though, thanks!